# I've output data from R using openxlsx and want to add superscript in part of the title string

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm using openxlsx package to output a data table into excel. I've given the table a title. Is there a way to make part of the title superscript?

For example how can i make the '1,2,3' part of this string superscript:

```
# creates table title
writeData(wb, tab_name,
          'my table title 1,2,3',
          startCol = 1, startRow = 2)
```

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this!